# How do I send different SSLCertificateFile based on SSL_TLS_SNI environment variable?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, wildcard-subdomain, sni

Idea is to run a wildcard cert off an internal CA for *.domain.com, while public-facing domain.com site is validated by a world recognized CA. Application serving requests is the same though, so I'd think keeping a **single** VirtualHost configuration section would be nice. The question is about doing it in a **single** section.

Comment: What parts of [the documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI) and [various](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm) [tutorials](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/serving-secure-sites-with-sni-on-apache) [about](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-with-apache-on-ubuntu-12-04) [SNI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981341/apache-sni-multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-address) are unclear?

Comment: My specific question is whether this is possible to do in a SINGLE VirtualHost section. I'm quite aware that I can define multiple sections and include the longer configuration in each one.

Answer (score 4):

You don't. Apache handles that:

```
<NameVirtualHost *:443>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName www.yoursite.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/site
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /path/to/www_yoursite_com.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/www_yoursite_com.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt
</Virtual Host>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName www.yoursite2.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /path/to/www_yoursite2_com.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/www_yoursite2_com.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt
</Virtual Host>
```

Comment: I ended up centralizing the configuration using mod_macro

Comment: Good one. @lkraav I would like to improve the original question and put a new answer. The question is similar like this: https://serverfault.com/questions/1095421/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-variable-for-sslcertificatefile-from-http-host-or/