# Is it possible to generate a variable for SSLCertificateFile from HTTP_HOST (or something similar)?

Tags: apache-2.4

Normally in my vhost blocks I do:

```
Define SITE example.com

SSLCertificateFile /path/to/${SITE}.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/${SITE}.key
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a variable in Apache that would correspond to my filenames for `example.com.crt` and `example.com.key`?

I assume not, but it's worth asking to consolidate my vhost blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Apache, you can use [mod_macro](https://www.cri.ensmp.fr/%7Ecoelho/mod_macro/)

First define a VHost Macro for repetitive configurations:

```
 <Macro VHost $host $port $dir>
  Listen $port
  <VirtualHost *:$port>

    ServerName $host
    DocumentRoot $dir

    <Directory $dir>
      # do something here...
    </Directory>

    # limit access to intranet subdir.
    <Directory $dir/intranet>
      order deny,allow
      deny from all
      allow from 10.0.0.0/8
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
</Macro>
```

Then you can use of VHost with different arguments.

```
Use VHost www.apache.org 80 /projects/apache/web
Use VHost www.perl.com 8080 /projects/perl/web
Use VHost www.ensmp.fr 1234 /projects/mines/web
```

I've got 50 domains (like a.com, b.com, c.com, d.com, etc) based on the same wordpress code directory. While convert to https, every domain has its own certificate and private key files. I don't want to copy & paste & change the VirtualHost block codes for 50 times.

By mod_macro I don't need to do the VirtualHost block 50 times. I did it this way, which makes it easier. Below macro include redirect www to non-www domain name:

```
<Macro VHost $domain>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.$domain
    Redirect permanent / https://$domain/

    Include /path/to/apache-common-ssl.conf

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/$domain.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/$domain.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/$domain-fullchain.cer
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName $domain
    DocumentRoot /home/wordpress
    <Directory /home/wordpress>
        # Stuff about the directory ...
    </Directory>

    Include /path/to/apache-common-ssl.conf

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/$domain.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/$domain.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/$domain-fullchain.cer
</VirtualHost>
</Macro>

Use VHost a.com
Use VHost b.com
Use VHost c.com
......
```

Comment: Nice, but could you please modify your answer so that the macro directly solves the problem in the question. In particular, please include the SSLCertificateKey and KeyFIle.

Comment: If someone confirms this works, and I'm sure it does, I'll mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: By your question, I found mod_macro, it also solved my question. @jeff

Answer (score 1):

Apache wants to read the certificates on startup, so you won't be able to define them runtime (i.e. during handshake).